# How to Register New Directory Path as a variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Quick question is it possible to create a directory using the file module and register the path of the new directory so that you can use it as a variable.

I would love to do this because I am creating a directory with timestamp but now I would love to use that directory to store some data and seems like when I use the lookup plugin it fails because the time changes when...

Here is the first two tasks where I create two directories;

```sh
- name: Create Directory with timestamp to store the data if it doesn't exist
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  file:
    path: "{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "0755"
```

```sh
- name: Create Directory with timestamp to store data that was run multiple times that day
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  file:
    path: "{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}/{{ansible_date_time.time}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "0755"
```

I am using this variable in the other tasks to store some data in that directory which works really well ... `"{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}"` but now the issue is when it comes to retrieving a file in that directory using the lookup plugin it fails because the second directory which is a time stamp can't be found because the lookup plugin is actually looking for a directory with a different time which is the current time when the task is being executed which is different from when the second task was executed.

Kindly assist, I have thought of trying the stat feature but I don't know how to execute that thought.

my lookup task

```sh
- name: Deploy to the server
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['Servers']
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{hostvars['dummy']['user']}}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file','{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}/{{ansible_date_time.time}}/file') }}"
```

Comment: Have you tried `register`-ing the result of the `file` task and inspecting the result?

Comment: Yeah, I have got an error ..

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute

Comment: Any ideas on how to debug?? after register

Comment: You would have to show us the code that is generating the error.

Comment: Here:


```sh
- name: Create Directory with timestamp to store data that was run multiple times that day
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  file:
    path: "{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}/{{ansible_date_time.time}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "0755"
  register: dir_path


- debug:
    msg: "{{dir_path.stdout}}"
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `lookup` happens on Ansible control machine. So if you are creating directories on target, and trying to `lookup` that directory, it is going to fail anyway.

Comment: So what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. You can keep the public keys on the Ansible control machine and use `lookup`:

   ```yaml
   # example: use /home/ansible/.ssh/dummy_id_rsa.pub on ansible control machine
   - authorized_key:
       user: "{{ hostvars['dummy']['user'] }}"
       key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/.ssh/dummy_id_rsa.pub') }}"
       state: "present"
   ```
2. Pass the public key as a string:

   ```yaml
   vars:
     dummy_pub_key: "ssh-rsa AAAABC12x........... dummy@localhost"

   tasks:
   - authorized_key:
       user: "{{ hostvars['dummy']['user'] }}"
       key: "{{ dummy_pub_key }}"
       state: "present"
   ```

**Update:**

Oh, and for your original question on saving the created path into variable:

```yaml
- name: Create Directory with timestamp to store the data if it doesn't exist
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['local']
  file:
    path: "{{store_files_path}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "0755"
  register: newdir_res
- name: show the newly created directory path
  debug:
    msg: "Directory path is {{ newdir_res.path }}"
```

Comment: I am also creating the SSH keys from a task also, so this is quite impossible to do, but let me see if I can echo it out and place it as a variable.

Comment: Yes, I have shown the public key by setting it in `vars`. But you should be able to `cat` the file and store it in variable too. I updated answer for the original question as well.

Comment: Ohhhh, so that's where I was confusing myself I will use your answer. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Hey I need some help @seshadri_c

Comment: The solution worked, but still I am unable to do the lookup on the enviroment thing.

Comment: Hey.. Do you mind starting a new question with the details?

Comment: Sure let me do so now.